# Why Pandas library is not reading updated Excel files from Blob storage using in Azure Synapse Spark Pool?

Tags: python, pandas, azure, apache-spark, azure-synapse

***Subject: pd.ExcelFile() is not reading updated Excel files in Synapse Spark Pool from Blob storage while Synapse Notebook Karnel runs.***

I'm facing an issue reading updated Excel files in my Azure Synapse Spark Pool (version 3.3) using Python 3.11. My setup involves:

Data source: Excel file stored in Azure Blob storage.
Update process: The file is updated periodically with new data from SharePoint using Microsoft Power Automate.
Reading data: I use pandas.ExcelFile() in my Synapse notebook to read the Excel file.

Problem:

- When the notebook runs for the first time, it successfully reads the data,  by passing the abfss path to an Excel (xls or xlsx) file from the initial ExcelFile(), upload and populates the data frame.

`xlsx = pd.ExcelFile(file_path)`

`wb = pd.read_excel(xlsx,sheet_name='discount')`

- However, if the notebook is already running and the Excel file is updated in SharePoint (triggering a Power Automate flow to update the Blob storage), I encounter an error: HttpResponseError: The range specified is invalid for the current size of the resource.

```
RequestId:8a416b5b-401e-0070-6581-6e06f0000000
Time:2024-03-04T22:16:21.5453793Z
ErrorCode:InvalidRange
Content: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>InvalidRange</Code><Message>The range specified is invalid for the current size of the resource.
```

If I stop the Spark pool and restart the notebook Karnel, the updated Excel file will be read correctly again.

Questions:

1. Why does pd.ExcelFile() fails to read the updated Excel file while the notebook runs, resulting in the HttpResponseError.
2. Is there a way to read the updated file without restarting the kernel, potentially leveraging the Excel file mechanisms?

I've searched for solutions regarding the issue, but the only solution to make it work was forcing refresh and running the script with pd.ExcelFile() again. But that is not sustainable, and I need to make it work with the update to the data frame. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When I tried the below:

```
import pandas as pd
import adlfs
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.key.stgsynp.dfs.core.windows.net", "TzXfEEHLnOojJcE1lqfV4HV9rK0BDpZaHq/Yqo6eH3ZKclogX5zDGwby2EMov8xmdZezCDdGWlv5+AStNeictA==")
file_path = "abfss://folder02@stgsynp.dfs.core.windows.net/sheet1.xlsx"
def read_excel_file(file_path, sheet_name='Sheet1'):
    fs = adlfs.AzureBlobFileSystem(account_name='stgsynp', account_key='TzXfEEHLnOojJcE1lqfV4HV9rK0BDpZaHq/Yqo6eH3ZKclogX5zDGwby2EMov8xmdZezCDdGWlv5+AStNeictA==')
    with fs.open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
        df = pd.read_excel(f, sheet_name=sheet_name)
    return df
df = read_excel_file(file_path)
print("Initial data:")
print(df)
```

I encounter the ERROR

```
HttpResponseError: The specifed resource name contains invalid characters.
```

I have tried the below approach:

```
import pandas as pd
def read_excel_file(file_path, sheet_name='Sheet1'):
    df = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name=sheet_name)
    return df
file_path = 'https://stgsynp.dfs.core.windows.net/folder02/sheet1.xlsx?sv=2022-11-02&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacupyx&se=2024-03-05T17:52:01Z&st=2024-03-05T09:52:01Z&spr=https&sig=uMKiqL4JXL%2FT0sZcjargX1GjDEL7eaWtzRIPyVxYn6U%3D'
df = read_excel_file(file_path)
print("Initial data:")
print(df)
```

**Results:**

```
updated data:
      Name  Age         City
0   Thomas   26  small heath
1     jhon   22  small heath
2      Ada   16  small heath
3  aurthur   30  small heath
4   fredie   30  small heath
5      sai   99   shamshabad
```

In the above code defined a function `(read_excel_file)` takes two arguments: file_path (the path to the Excel file) and sheet_name (the name of the sheet to read, defaulting to 'Sheet1').

It uses pandas `read_excel` function to read the specified Excel file and sheet into a DataFrame `(df)`.

The `pandas.read_excel` method does not support accessing Excel files using the **wasbs** or **abfss** scheme URLs.

In this case use SAS token:

To create a **SAS** token via the Azure portal for accessing an Azure Storage account:

Navigate to the Azure portal and select your Azure Storage account.
Go to the settings section of your storage account.
Click on "Shared access signature" to generate a **SAS** token.

```
ReadExcel=pd.read_excel('https://<account name>.dfs.core.windows.net/<file system>/<path>?<sas token>')  
print(ReadExcel)
```

**Reference:** [Azure Synapse Workspace - How to read an Excel file from Data Lake Gen2 using Pandas or PySpark?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/93296/azure-synapse-workspace-how-to-read-an-excel-file)

Comment: Thanks for reaching out! To clarify, the issue I'm experiencing is not related to accessing the dataset values themselves. It specifically occurs when I try to refresh the data within the same Synapse notebook session.
Here's the scenario:
I load the dataset into the notebook.
While the notebook session is still running, the Excel sheet containing the data gets updated.
I encountered an error when retrieving the data again during the same session.
I hope to find a way to ensure the notebook refreshes with the latest data even if the source is updated mid-session.